# Fast method for adds the selected elements of a jlist in another jlist

Tags: java

I must select many item from a jList1 and add them in another jList2 when I click them. I have writed a method for jList1 but doesn't work:

```
private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
    elenco[indice]=jList1.getSelectedValue().toString();
    indice++;
    jList2.setListData(elenco);
}
```

I have a java.lang.NullPointerException. `elenco` is a String[]. What's the best method to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to assign a String[] object to __elenco__, e.g. "__elenco = new String [50]__"?

Comment: No, I have inizialize it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar requirement and here is a working code

EDIT: Pasting elaborated code.

```
List<String>selectedValues = new ArrayList<String>();

List<String> selected = jList1.getSelectedValuesList();
//List to hold selected values. 
selectedValues.addAll(selected);    

jList2.setListData(selectedValues.toArray(new String[0]));

List<String>remainingValues = new LinkedList<>();
for(int index=0; index<jList1.getModel().getSize(); index++){
    String str = jList1.getModel().getElementAt(index);
    if( ! selectedValues.contains(str)){
        remainingValues.add(str);
    }
}
//getRemainingValuesList() returns the values remaining after selection
jLis1.setListData(remainingValues);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but selectedValues.addAll(selected) in netbeans I have an error

Comment: what is the error? would you like to paste that over here?

Comment: getRemainingValuesList() and selectedValues() cannot find symbols

Comment: :)
You would need to define those by your own. That was a snippet of my code. Let me edit the answer and put complete code.

Comment: doesn't works for two reasons: first, I have this exception since I must put the casting for remainingValues: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector. Second, select only the last item selected